# How to move to next row in cellTable using SelectionModel?

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

SelectionModel currently handles mouse click and keyboard on select row in cellTable.
How do I do it programmatically to move to next/prev row according to current selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your list of items find the currently selected item
2. Determine next item that would be selected
3. Call the [`SelectionModel.setSelected(T object, boolean selected)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/SelectionModel.html#setSelected%28T,%20boolean%29) method, passing your next object to be selected and `true` for the `selected` parameter.

To find the currently selected object (if you don't hold a reference to it anywhere) you can iterate over all the objects in the CellTable and check which one is selected by calling [`SelectionModel.isSelected(T object)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/SelectionModel.html#isSelected%28T%29) method.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the selection model directly, you can just use the JTable method:

```
setRowSelectionInterval
```

Comment: This question is about GWT which is Google Web Toolkit. JTable is part of Swing.